# iOS Share extension not working on image urls

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I have a share extension that uses those rules:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
```

It works perfectly for normal websites and images but I can't parse image urls like this : ( http://www.zappos.com/images/z/3/3/5/4/0/3/3354034-p-2x.jpg ). I tired to add other rules but still my share extension won't appear when I open this website with Safari and click share.

But if I make rule TRUEPREDICATE, my share extension can parse the site.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I am able to get the .jpg from safari by using only public.url and remove all child of public.image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of wj2061's answer, the following predicate will grab any and all attachments supplied by the host app.

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
<string>SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.item" ||
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.content"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
    ).@count > 0
</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

You did nothing wrong,it's just because the common keys (of the following chart) defined by Apple cannot include all cases.

[image]

For your case , you have to write your own  NSPredicate String as Apple suggested here:[Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8)

I changed apple's example like this:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>SUBQUERY (
                  extensionItems,
                  $extensionItem,
                   SUBQUERY (
                     $extensionItem.attachments,
                     $attachment,
                     ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image";
                   ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
                ).@count == 1
       </string>
    </dict>
```

You can change `public.image` to any other [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_conc/understand_utis_conc.html).

Some of the common UTIs are listed below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                (
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;com.adobe.pdf&quot;
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;public.image&quot;
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO &quot;public.url&quot;
                )
                ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
                ).@count > 0</string>
```

The last line @count > 0 did the trick for me.